# Создание thumbnail для записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, допустим с помощью парсера получаю url картинки на сайте, с которого нужно скопировать картинки. И нужно создать thumbnail для определённой записи.
Скопировать нужно в папку, созданную с помощью плагина, допустим thumbdir.
Что нужно указывать для поля guid при вызове функции wp_insert_attachment ?
т.е. функция wp_upload_dir возвращает массив, в котором есть такие свойства: baseurl и basedir. Какое из этих свойств нужно указать для guid ? 
Название папки у меня такое: /wp-content/uploads/thumbdir

```
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Вставляем запись в базу данных.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUID - сокращение от Globally Unique Identifier. В качестве такового для поста (которым и attachment тоже является), WordPress использует **url** поста. То есть ни о каких файловых путях там речи быть не может.

Пример кода, который вы взяли с сайта kama, правильный. Его надо использовать как есть.